# Inserted element in menu strange behavior on only 1 page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Updated an old javascript menu to a newer jquery platform menu [here](https://www.frankandlindy.com/index.php)

Notice the arrows in the menu are top aligned to the letters in the menu, this is not desired. Every other page, the arrows are center aligned to the letters and working as desired, [here](https://www.frankandlindy.com/history.php)

I have spent several hours inspecting the pages side by side, looking at both properties, thought the flexslider on the home page might be having an issue, so I disabled it and the issue still remained.

I just don't understand, the menu is 'included' in each page, so i am sure there is no difference in the instructions to the client, but something is interfering, and I just cant find the issue.

Just looking for a starting place, removed elements above and below the menu element and no change, so a point in the correct direction to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Jeff

PS, would post code, but not sure what code to post?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doctype is different on both pages. Try setting the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: This was it, dont know why i didnt look up there, thank you very much